# How do I read this piece of OCaml code that uses "~" and ":"?

Tags: ocaml

I'm new to OCaml and when browsing some code I saw the following:

```
  let catch f m = M.bind m ~f:(
      function Error e -> f e
             | Ok x -
    )
```

From what I can make out this is defining a try/catch block (my understanding is that OCaml doesn't use a seperate catch block). `M.bind` is the monadic bind operator that passes m's result to the 2nd computation. The OCaml reference manual says that ~ is used to label arguments for ease of understanding their type signature in documentation. However does that mean the second computation (the "`function ..`") is also labeled f??

Comment: The code isn't complete. It's not even syntactically valid. But even if it is, not knowing what `M` and `m` is  makes it difficult to interpret. It's reasonable to assume that `M.bind` is monadic bind, as you do, and it's also apparent that `M.bind` passes `f` a `result`, but tit's difficult to say much more about it.

Comment: I also don't know what it means for the second computation to be "labeled". But the `f` inside it refe4rs to the argument to `catch`, not anything defined by `M.bind`.

Comment: @glennsl: the code is part of a larger file which definitely compiles. I just didn't provide that additional context.

Comment: You should always provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A labeled argument is associated with a particular function. It means that the function has an argument with a name. When you call the function, you specify the name and the value like this:

```
 myfun ~name: value
```

If this call is valid, then we know that `myfun` has an argument with the name `name`.

For comparison, when you call a function without a labelled argument, the call looks like this:

```
myotherfun othervalue
```

The definition of a function that takes a named argument looks like this:

```
let myfun ~name =
    ... expression involving name ...
```

For example this function makes a singleton list out of whatever you pass it:

```
let myfun ~name = [name]
```

A call to this function looks as follows in the OCaml toplevel (REPL):

```
# myfun ~name: 44;;
- : int list = [44]
```

The key is that this allows you to specify arguments by name rather than by position when you call the function. You need to specify the name(s) that the function is expecting. But if a function has more than one named argument you can specify them in any order.

It's not true that these names are only used in OCaml documentation. What the manual is telling you is that named arguments act as good documentation as to what the different arguments are used for. This is especially true for functions that take a lot of arguments, and even more especially if some of them are the same type. Using names avoids the kind of error where you specify them in the wrong order.

So, you're calling a function `M.bind` that has a labeled argument with the name `f`. Conventionally, arguments named `f` are used to pass a function as an argument, which is indeed what's happening here.

So; your question seems to be whether the second argument is labeled. The second argument of `M.bind` is labeled, yes. But the value can be anything. A value is not affected by the label of the function that it's being passed to. Furthermore, you can look at the function definition `function Error ...` and see that it doesn't have any labeled arguments. It's just a function that accepts a value of `result` type.

To repeat, this is a function definition:

```
function Error -> f e | Ok x -> g x
```

So we know everything there is to know about this function. It definitely doesn't have any named arguments.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, the second argument to bind (which has to be a function given the type of bind) is in this case being labeled with f?  Also I was being sloppy in my language - I ought to have said "formal parameter" not "argument" - so I think what you're saying is that its not just formal parameters that can be named but arguments too. So that makes things clearer, although the the reuse of "f" still seems likely to cause confusion.

Comment: A function either has named arguments or it doesn't. If it has named arguments, then when you call the function you supply the names. The names you supply when you call the function have to be the same as the names the function is defined to accept. There's no real possible confusion as far as I can see.

Comment: It seems to me you're not getting the essence of the idea: if a function is defined with named arguments, the caller needs to supply these exact names when making the call. But the arguments can appear in any order. (There are in fact some complexities that we can talk about later.)

Comment: Ok your last comment did finally clear up my confusion thanks but I think what was contributing to some of the confusion is that when you say "arguments" in your 1st comment, I think that in fact you mean "parameters". That is " A function either has named parameters or it doesn't..." Then when you call that function, the arguments you supply also have to have the same labels as their corresponding parameters (if any). I hope I have  it right now.